# how to write results in a for loop to multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, contextmanager

I have

```
with open ('~/abc.csv', 'w') as f:
    write1 = csv.write(f)
    write1.writerow(['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'])

with open ('~/def.csv', 'w') as g:
    write2 = csv.write(g)
    write2.writerow(['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5', 'header6'])

for iteration in a_list:
    perform calculations
    result1 = ([h1, h2, h3, h4],[l1, l2, l3, l4],[m1, m2, m3, m4], ...,[])
    for pa in result1:
        write1.writerow(pa)

    def fun(result1):
        result2 = ([n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6],[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6], [], ...[])
        for pb in result2:
             write2.writerow(pb)
```

Expecting two csv files as

```
'header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'
h1, h2, h3, h4
l1, l2, l3, l4
m1, m2, m3, m4
      :
```

and

```
'header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5', 'header6'
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6
```

This can be easily done when all the iterations are completed and separate appended(list) result1 and result2 can be easily written to separate files using  writer.writerows(pa). However, I would like to write to csv files in each iteration, so that I wouldn't miss if I have to break the loop for some reason.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix your code's indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place two files in a context manager and have two `csv.writer` objects (since Python 2.7):

```
with open ('~/abc.csv', 'w') as f, open ('~/def.csv', 'w') as g:
    writer1 = csv.writer(f)
    writer2 = csv.writer(g)

    writer1.writerow(['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'])    
    writer2.writerow(['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5', 'header6'])

    for iteration in a_list:
        # perform calculations
        for pa in result1:
            writer1.writerow(pa)
        for pb in result2:
            writer2.writerow(pb)
```

From the docs (which are the same for Python [2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) up to [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)).

> With more than one item, the context managers are processed as if multiple with statements were nested:

```
with A() as a, B() as b:
    suite
```

> is equivalent to

```
with A() as a:
    with B() as b:
        suite
```

This suggests the other way of doing it which is to have the nesting go one layer deeper.

```
with open ('~/abc.csv', 'w') as f:
    with open ('~/def.csv', 'w') as g:
        writer1 = csv.writer(f)
        writer2 = csv.writer(g)
        ...
```

Comment: with open ('~/abc.csv', 'w') as f, open ('~/def.csv', 'w') as g:  invalid syntax

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This works for me in Python 2.7.

Comment: Python version 3.4.3

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) it's valid in 3.4 too.

Comment: I missed the first line. I used with for the second file also. Thank you for the support Jamie!

Comment: Probably my bad. That was what I put originally without noticing. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you only have one writer variable declared. You would need a second writer variable.

```
fWriter = csv.write(f)

...

gWriter = csv.write(g)

...

fWriter.writerow(pa)

...

gWriter.writerow(pb)
```

Comment: I used different write variable defined. However, I missed it when converting to sample code here

Comment: You can edit your sample code so people don't waste their time on things which aren't the real problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited!